# I have created a code in python using Flask to insert information in a database

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm trying to insert an information in a database. I have created a function in a code (see bellow) to insert a task using the html but I'm not sure the correct syntax to input date format. I have done a try inserting the information directly in the database using the Workbench and to fix the data format issue I have used the "str_to_date" but I do not know how to insert date thru the Code once it will be updated by the html page... is it correct to use the "str_to_date" alternative also in the python code to avoid error during the data input thru HTML?

```
def insert_action(task):
    cursor = get_connection().cursor()
    insert = ('INSERT INTO task(id_request, Task, Description, Responsible, email, Issue_Date, Due_Date, Priority, Task_status)VALUES (default, %s, %s, %s, %s,str_to_date(%s, "%m-%d-%Y"), str_to_date(%s, "%m-%d-%Y"), %s, %s)')
    data = (task.Action, task.Description, task.Responsible, task.email, task.Issue_Date, task.Due_Date, task.Priority, task.task_status)
    cursor.execute(insert, data)
    get_connection().commit()
    return cursor.lastrowid
```

Comment: In Python code you can convert strings to dates using `date.strptime`, and `date.strftime` to convert dates to strings.  See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: it looks like the question is about datetime, so i have added code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

converting date to string (and back):

- string to date: `strptime`
- date to string: `strftime`

Here is example code:

```
import datetime as dt

# string to date
date_string = '21 jan 2025'
date_value = dt.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d %b %Y')

print(date_value)


# date to string
date_string = dt.datetime.strftime(date_value, 'dd-mmm-yyyy')
print(date_string)
```

Here is a useful link:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime
or use the official python docs.